# Xcode says found nil, but actual value is not nil

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to get a value from Firebase Firestore, but for some reason, xcode says that it found nil while unwrapping an optional. I put a check in place to display something else if it is nil, but it still goes in my `if`, and I am not sure why.

Here is my code:

```
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let docRef = db.collection("Users").document(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)
        docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists {
                let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
                let points = document.data()!["points"]
                print(points)
                if (points != nil) {
                    self.pointsLabel.text = "\(points!)"
                }
                else {
                    self.pointsLabel.text = "There was an error getting your points"
                }
            } else {
                print("Document does not exist")
            }
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: *xcode says that it found nil while unwrapping an optional* - at which line?

Comment: It was actually something much simpler. Somehow, my IBOutlet got disconnected! Thanks for all your great suggestions though, everybody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possibility is your `pointsLabel`. If you are using IBOutlet for the label and your Firebase callback is called before the view is load, then the error like that may happen.

But you should let us know at which line the error happened.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this line:

```
let points = document.data()!["points"]
```

is not checked against `nil`.

What if `document.data()` is `nil`?